# Unable to transfer file from Linux to Windows machine with scp

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, zsh, command

Through Shell script, I've to transfer files/directories from Linux machine to Windows shared location hence tried with following command -

```
scp <directory-location-path-on-linux>/pom.xml "\\\\<ip-address-or-hostname>\\Shared\\test"
```

this does not give any output on console and also cannot see file copied to destination.

```
scp <username>@<host-ip-of-linux(i.e. of source)>:<directory-location-path-on-linux>/pom.xml "\\\\<ip-address-or-hostname>\\Shared\\test"
```

This asks for password and after providing password, gives following output on console -

```
pom.xml                                                       100% 4966     6.2MB/s   00:00
```

but file is not copied to destination.

Could you please help to understand what could be wrong here?

**Note: ** Destination shared location has read/write access to everyone.

Comment: `scp` is used to copy files via an `ssh` server. This is the wrong tool to access `smb` shares.

Comment: Ok, but answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235778/scp-from-linux-to-windows suggested what I did. Could you please suggest another best solution?

Comment: `smbclient`, https://askubuntu.com/questions/749070/copy-file-with-smbclient-and-path-to-directory

Answer (score 3):

In order to copy files using `scp`, you need to have an ssh server running on the target machine. The correct format, *if* you actually had an ssh server running, would have been:

```
scp /path/on/linux/pom.xml ip-address-or-hostname:/remote/path
```

When you ran this:

```
scp <directory-location-path-on-linux>/pom.xml "\\\\<ip-address-or-hostname>\\Shared\\test"
```

or this:

```
scp <username>@<host-ip-of-linux(i.e. of source)>:<directory-location-path-on-linux>/pom.xml "\\\\<ip-address-or-hostname>\\Shared\\test"
```

You actually created a file named `\\<ip-address-or-hostname>\Shared\test` in the current directory of your Linux system. You should be able to see it with `ls`. For example:

```
$ scp file "\\\192.168.1.1\\foo"
$ ls
'\\192.168.1.1\foo'   file
```

Based on the fact that you are using `\\\`, I assume what you really want to do is copy the file onto a drive that is being shared by the Windows host using the SMB protocol. The normal way of doing this is to mount the SMB-shared drive on your Linux, and then just use `cp`.

There are dozens of resources explaining how to do this. These two, which are just two of the top hits I found when searching for "linux mount samba", should serve as a starting point:

- [Mounting and mapping shares between Windows and Linux with Samba](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/samba-windows-linux)
- [8 ways to mount smbfs (samba file system) in Linux.](https://www.linuxnix.com/8-ways-to-mount-smbfs-samba-file-system-in-linux/)